# Including a .pdf to acompany the pdfLatex code that generated it

Tags: support

When submitting a Minimal Example how do I attach the resulting .pdf output?

Comment: @christianhupfer You sent me an answer to my question on the use of the `etoc` package and attached the .pdf image of what the code produced. **How is this done?**

Comment: It's screen shot made in Adobe Reader  only and added as `.png` or `.jpg`file

Comment: take a look at the answers here: [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StackExchange does not support file attachments.  You have two options:

- Take a screenshot of the relevant part of the PDF and insert it in the question.  This is the best option in most cases because it focuses on the problem and it is immediately visible to readers.
- Use an external file hosting service such as Dropbox or http://ge.tt to upload the PDF and link to it.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase my request: A few hours ago I posted a question under the `etoc` tag, accompanied by an MWE, which was satisfactorily answered a short time later by @ChristianHupfer. The answer comprised my edited MWE **and** the .pdf result of running that code. I have seen similar done many times on the Stack Exchange, but never found a hint anywhere how it's done. I suppose your answer is that Christian took a screenshot and inserted it. If so, I will (a) be happy and (b) mark your response down as being the answer.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: Yes, that's the way how it works. You can accept Szabolcs' answer

Comment: to all three of you: I know I am breaking the rules here, but ... THANKS